# How can you get the return value of a Windows thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, return-value

I was just wondering if it is possible (and if so, how) to get the return value of a thread in C++ (Windows). I have several threads, and I use `WaitForMultipleObjects(...)` on them. This waits until a thread is done, and returns the index of said thread, and all is well. However, I want to be able to obtain the return value of the thread that finished using its handle.

For example:

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread1(void *parameter){
    ...
    if(...) return 0;
    else return -1;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread2(void *parameter){
    ...
    if(...) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){
    HANDLE t1 = CreateThread(0, 0, Thread1, NULL, 0, 0);
    HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(0, 0, Thread2, NULL, 0, 0);
    HANDLE *threads = new HANDLE[2];
    threads[0] = t1;
    threads[1] = t2;
    int result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, threads, false, INFINITE);
    if(result == 0){
        //get the threads value here:
        int retVal = SomeFunction(t1); //What is SomeFunction?
    }
    ...
}
```

I have tried to use `GetExitCodeThread(thread)` but I'm assuming this returns a system exit code, as it always gives me a very strange integer. Does anyone know a way, or a workaround?

Comment: I've always used GetExitCodeThread. Are you sure you're using it correctly? It takes a thread handle and a pointer to a DWORD and returns the success of GetExitCodeThread (_not_ the return value of the thread).

Comment: Your question is my answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GetExitCodeThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the correct function. Here is the MSDN description of what it does:

> This function returns immediately. If the specified thread has not
>   terminated and the function succeeds, the status returned is
>   STILL_ACTIVE. If the thread has terminated and the function succeeds,
>   the status returned is one of the following values:
>
> - The exit value specified in the ExitThread or TerminateThread function.
> - The return value from the thread function.
> - The exit value of the thread's process.

Comment: `GetExitCodeThread(t1, &retVal)` and returned 4294967295 (retVal being a DWORD). The actual return value in the thread was -1. I just figured out the ints rebounded to negatives. Sigh...

Answer (score 3):

The problem with most programmer is that they don't pay attention to compiler warnings. At level 4 (/W4), the compiler produces following warning when returning `-1` from a function that is returning `DWORD`:

`warning C4245: 'return' : conversion from 'int' to 'DWORD', signed/unsigned mismatch`

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for STILL_ACTIVE for the values one of these threads may still be active

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ 11's threads concepts using `std::future`.
See an example below.

```
int ReturnFrmThread() {
    return 100;
}

int main() {
    std::future<int> GetRetVal= std::async(ReturnFrmThread);  // Execution of ReturnFrmThread starts
    int answer = GetAnAnswer.get(); // gets value as 100; 
    // Waits until ReturnFrmThread has finished
}
```